# Understanding multiple assignments in Python

Tags: python

What is the difference between this:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

And this:

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

I'm trying to follow along in the examples in the documentation and the first form (multiple assignment syntax) seems complicated to me. I tried to simplify it with the second example but it's not giving the same results. I'm clearly interpreting the first statement wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple assignment evaluates the values of *everything* on the right hand side *before* changing any of the values of the left hand side.

In other words, the difference is this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = b                  # a = 2
b = a + b              # b = 2 + 2
```

vs. this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a + b        # a, b = 2, 1 + 2
```

---

Another way of thinking about it is that it's the equivalent of constructing a tuple and then deconstructing it again (which is actually exactly what's going on, except without an explicit intermediate tuple):

```
a = 1
b = 2
_tuple = (b, a+b)
a = _tuple[0]
b = _tuple[1]
```

Comment: You might wanna illustrate your second example with the use use of a `tmp` variable

Comment: @jamylak That is what `_tuple` is.